# Assigning different weights to different users' sentiment and displaying in geospatial analysis

Tags: python, python-2.7, geospatial, arcgis, arcpy

I have the following data:

```
PERSON  POWER_USER  DATE    TIME    SENTIMENT   LOCATION    WEIGHT
Person A    Yes     3/5/2015    12:00   0.8     LA          1.5
Person A    Yes     3/5/2015    12:01   0.7     LA          1.5
Person B    No      3/5/2015    14:00   -0.5    LA          1
Person B    No      3/5/2015    15:00   0.1     LA          1
Person A    Yes     3/5/2015    16:00   0.4     LA          1.5
Person D    Yes     3/5/2015    17:00   -0.1    WA          1.5
```

I would like to compute an "average" sentiment score by location. But for power-user I would like to assign, say, 1.5x the weight for their sentiment since they are more influential. How can I do that with ArcGIS, Arcpy, or any geospatial analysis tool?

I do know how to do this without the weight consideration in Arcgis.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is more to the question than what I'm understanding, but do you want to create for instance a total **Score** field, where *Sentiment* gets weighted by *Power_User* for each row?

You can use the [Field Calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Calculate_Field_examples/005s0000002m000000/) to populate a new **Score** field as follows:

[image: Field Calculator]

This for the Pre-Logic Script Codeblock:

```
def CalculateScore(sentiment, poweruser):
    weight = 1.5 if poweruser == "Yes" else 1.0
    return sentiment*weight
```

And this for the main Expression:

```
CalculateScore( !Sentiment! , !Power_User! )
```

Be sure to select the *Python* parser.

---

Then to aggregate by *Location* and find the "average" score per location - e.g. LA, WA... - I believe you can use the [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000) tool.

Statistics Field = *Score*, Statistic Type = *Mean*, Case Field = *Location*

[image: Summary Stats]
[image: Stat Table]

Let us know if this is what you were after.